# Authentication against Active Directory using a Mobile Device

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, mobile-application

I currently have a Mobile Application that communicates through a WCF Service to access a Database. The Mobile App can access on the network as well as externally. It connects to the WCF Service which is hosted on one server inside the network. From there the WCF Service is pointing at another server which is hosting the Database that the Mobile Device is accessing.

With the above process how would you setup authentication using Active Directory which would confirm  the user of the Mobile Application before it can access the WCF Service to confirm that the user is a member of AD and they can then login after authorization is complete. This would occur as the user opens up the Application. Would this be coded into the App to prompt for the information, then send the information to the WCF Service which would then allow access? If not this then are there any other ways or information/links that can be provided please?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the BUILD 2013 videos. Visual Studio 2013 will create a webproject that will automagically do all that for you (I think). Just bare in mind, it uses the Microsoft.OWin.Security beta packages.

Also...you will need to install the AspNetWebTools2013 package first...

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauthoptions

Comment: This would apply to web projects and doesn't really assist me in working with Mobile Devices. Also I don't want to be waiting around for a solution I can use in the future, 2013 is only at preview release.

Comment: 2013 is a Go-Live preview. It has production level support from Microsoft this time round. Secondly, a mobile device IS a web device...how do you think WCF typically connects to a service? Its all HTTP...

Comment: So you're suggesting create the application in this and it should do it all for me correct?